# oauth_problem=nonce_used magento api in postman tool

Tags: api, magento, oauth, postman

[image]

Please guide me for magento rest API for fetching all product from magento using postman tool.

Answer (score 0):

The `nonce` parameter is supposed to be randomly generated every time you make a request.

If you're generating it yourself, make sure it's different each time - it doesn't matter what it is as long as it's unique.

More information about the `nonce` parameter [is available here](http://oauth.net/core/1.0/#nonce).